# qwinsta --"Error [5] - Access is denied"

Tags: remote-access, remote-desktop

I am getting the "access is denied" error even though I have no problem connecting with Remote Desktop Connection.  My computer is Win7, the targets are WinXP or Server 2003.
Perhaps I am specifying the SERVER name incorrectly:
`qwinsta /SERVER:XXYYZZ02`
I have tried
`qwinsta /SERVER:\\XXYYZZ02`
`qwinsta /SERVER:domain\XXYYZZ02`
`qwinsta /SERVER:domain/XXYYZZ02`
`qwinsta /SERVER:1.2.3.4`

Am I doing something wrong?  TIA...
(The problem I'm trying to solve is several support personnel needing to connect to the same servers and disconnecting each other mid-session.)

Comment: Did you get this working because even I am struggling with the same thing?

Comment: @dilip The OP at this SuperUser link commented that he got past it using PsExec (if that works for you, please comment back):  http://superuser.com/questions/650816/log-off-a-disconnected-user-remotely

Comment: `psexec \\remotepc cmd` followed by `qwinsta` worked for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

Found on Dell website, this worked for me same issue.

> This means the remote RPC component failed to execute the requested
> operation. It is because it is not allowed to operate on terminal
> service (Remote Desktop) through RPC by default.     To modify this
> setting to enable Remote Desktop API through RPC,  you need to find
> the following registry key:
>
> `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server`
>
> Then add a DWORD value named “AllowRemoteRPC” and change its value to
> 1.

In my case it was set to "0". I changed it to 1 and all was good.

Comment: That worked for me. Thanks. Here is the cmd: qwinsta console /server:<ip here>

Comment: @M_tek, How did you figure out this registry setting?

Comment: This also applies to the same symptom with `query.exe`, in which calls to `WinStationEnumerateW` return false, preventing use of `WinStationQueryInformationW`.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this link for the correct command names and alternatives: http://makezine.com/2007/08/15/howto-kill-terminal-services-s/

You might want to try executing from a cmd window run in administrator-mode.

Can you login any other way? e.g.: mstsc /console or via virtual console? I ask because then you can check the server authentication settings on the servers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have been testing in a shell run as Administrator.  From the article you linked, it appears as though I have the correct syntax for the command, as well.